# Eclipse on MacOS widget occurence on [ square bracket / Right-ALT+5

Tags: eclipse, macos, square-bracket

I am using Eclipse on MacOS.
Recently I did install some plugins...

Now I do see the following widget on pressing opening **[** square bracket (<kbd>RIGHT-ALT</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>):
[image: Eclipse Whoops]

Thought all I want is to print an opening square bracket.
I do not know what that is, what it wants, how to redefine keys for it or how to disable it.
Is there a way of removing it?

Comment: Is there a key binding set to that - 'Preferences > General > Keys'?

Comment: If I see it right it is "Share to Slack..."...I try getting rid of it...though any how-tos are welcome...thank you _greg-449_

Answer (score 1):

Look for a key binding in 'Preferences > General > Keys' (Preferences is on the Eclipse menu on macOS, the Window menu on other systems).

If there is a binding select that line and click the 'Unbind Command' button just below the table. This just removes the 'binding' between the command and the key sequence.

Comment: It cannot simply be removed since it is part of the plugin suite "CodeMix".  
So disabling the keyboard setting seems to be the best way.

Comment: Unbind Command does that - it just removes the binding from the command to the key sequenece. Any menu or toolbar option for that command remain unchanged.